# Why doesn't all values get iterated from object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, iteration

in jQuery - I have this:

```
//returns = Object {0: "17", 1: "16", 2: "24"}
console.log(lastColorsSelection);

$( lastColorsSelection).each(function( key, value) {   
    console.log(value[key]); //WHY?
});
```

Why does only the first value get logged in the loop? (17) I want 17,16 & 24 to be iterated through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.each() function not object.each()

```
$.each(lastColorsSelection,function( key, value) {   
    console.log(value); 
});
```

[Live Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcN3z/)

Comment: Ah. There it was. Thank you! :-) Sometimes the most simplest things isn't always that obvious. Your answer will be accepted when I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap the object into a jQuery object using `$(lastColorsSelection)` you get a jQuery object with only one item, and that item is the original object.

When you loop through all the items (one), the `key` will be `0` and the `value` will be the object, so getting `value[key]` will get the first item from the object.

Use the [`$.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of the [`each` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate the array, and show the `value`:

```
$.each(lastColorsSelection, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

In pure javascript this can be done as:

```
for(var key in lastColorsSelection){
    console.log(lastColorsSelection[key]);
}
```